# Angular JS Factory Clarification

Tags: angularjs

what is the difference between all these Factory definitions

```
app.factory('myFirstFactory', function () {

    var customShow = function () {
        return "My First Factory";
    }

    return customShow;

});



app.factory('mySecondFactory', function () {
    return {
        show: function () {
            return "My Second Factory";
        }
    }
});

app.factory('myThirdFactory', function () {
    function myCustomShow() { 
        return "My Third Factory";
    }
    return {
        show: myCustomShow
    }
});
```

Here is how its been called in the controller. What is the ideal case of defining the factory. What is the actual return type from the factory, In one defintion, it could seems like Factory and Service are look alike. Can someone please clarify

```
$scope.message1 = myFirstFactory();
$scope.message2 = myService.show();
$scope.message3 = mySecondFactory.show();
$scope.message4 = myThirdFactory.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one returns `customShow`. `customShow`is declared as a function. So the service returned by this factory is a function. So, when you inject `myFirstFactory`in a controller or another service, the injected value will be a function. BTW, you shouldn't choose `xxxFactory`as the name. The component you're defining, thanks to a factory, is a service, not a factory. What is injected is the returned service, not its factory.

The second one and the thirst one both return an object:

```
return {
    show: ...
}
```

So what will be injected in both cases is an object, and not a function like in the first case.

The returned object has a single field named `show`, which is a function. The second one defines a named function, and assigns this named function to the `show`property of the returned object, whereas the third one directly assigns an anonymous function to the `show`property of the returned object. But the end result is the same. The only difference you'll see is when printing (for debugging) the function itself:

```
console.log(theService.show);
```

will print

```
function myCustomShow() { ... }
```

for the second one, but will print

```
function () { ... }
```

for the third one.

Comment: Thanks Nizet. Couple more queries. In the secondFactory, anonymous function is assigned to show and it is being returned. If you look at the way its been called in the controller, its simply the name of the factory.
But in the third factory, we are assigning a named function to the show property.. I dont know have much knowledge on assigning a named function to property as i m from .net background, so could you please explain it for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: When declaring a named function as you're doing, you can refer to this function by its name, as if it was assigned to a variable.

Comment: Apologize for asking further
In this case, its assigning a fucntion to variable name.. rit??/ What is the benefit of this approach. Whats it been called.

 function myCustomShow() { 
        return "My Third Factory";
    }
    return {
        show: myCustomShow
    }

Answer (score 0):

It's all about your preference how to handle the interface of the factory. Another point is best practice. The third one is suggested by John Papa in his detailed [angular-styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#factories) even though he puts the the interface at the top and not below all functions due to readability. It's actually derived by the [Revealing Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).

The first remindes me of a class definiton if there is only a single function returned by the factory. Thus it has to be invoked when you inject it into your controller as follows:

```
function MyController($scope, myFirstFactory)
{
    // $scope.myFirstFactory would print out "My First Factory"
    $scope.myFirstFactory = myFirstFactory();
}
```

This is usually used if you plan to write object-oriented AngularJS services, since factories are useful to define a classes that you can instantiate many times using the new keyword, while services always create singletons.

```
app.factory('MyFirstFactory', function() {
    var privateVariable = 'foo';

    // Constructor
    var MyFirstFactory = function(bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    };

    MyFirstFactory.prototype.showCustom = function() {
        return "My Third Factory";
    };

    return MyFirstFactory;
});
```

You could then create many instances like so:

```
function MyController($scope, myFirstFactory)
{
    // $scope.myFirstFactory would print out "My First Factory"
    $scope.myFirstFactory = new MyFirstFactory();
    $scope.showCustom = myFirstFactory.showCustom();
}
```

The second is a variation of the third one which both return an object as @jb-nizet mentioned.

Comment: Thanks , i just looked at the blog and I just modified it. In the below code, the actual function definition is contained in customshow but why do we assign it to show and rahter than calling "customshow " directly, we are calling "Show". I m sure i m missing the basics here, but if you could explain, it would be great


    var service = {
      show: CustomShow
    };
    return service;

Comment: The variable `service` is actually what is meant to be the interface. Thats part of the Revealing Module Pattern. It makes it easier to read your code and allows it to be organized in a more structured manner. Another important fact here is the concept of pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. Lets say you have variables which are not defined within the `service` object and use this variable outside the factory and pass it into a function, then the variable is passed by value so any manipulation would have no effect on the variable outside the function. [see next comment].

Comment: Vise versa variables within objects are passed by reference so any modifications in functions outside the factory will have an effect on the object since its actually a reference. Of course it depends on what you want to achieve but I guess in most cases the object representation (interface notation) is a good way to go with.

Comment: Here is a simgple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13717/). As you can see the first approach uses `pass-by-value` and the second `pass-by-reference`. Only the second updates the value in the factory because a reference was passed into the function `updateName(names)`.

Comment: @LordTribunal, hi, i have posted another query related to angularjs, could you help me with it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654437/angularjs-resource-cache